# Grants distribution but with pejorative connotation

Tags: american-english, pejorative-language, jokes, russian

Is there a bitter phrase that signals pejorative connotations when talking about grants distribution? Unfortunately, grants system is not perfect and can be abused by irresponsible people who suck-up to a system.

In Russia we have "sawing grants" idiom. Are there analogous expression in English?

Comment: The negative idea here is not clear to me.

Comment: Living off of government largesse? Is that what sawing grants means, vs. doing real work like sawing wood?

Comment: Does "sawing grants" mean something like "budget cuts"?

Comment: There are two problems with this question, both of which warrant its closure until they're fixed. (1) there's not enough detail about the exact meaning you want to express. Please [edit] your post to explain the Russian idiom. Do you mean corruption? Political bias? Poor targeting? Obtuse or opaque rules? (2) When asking for a word or phrase, it's essential that you include a sample sentence showing how it would be used. For further guidance, see [ask]. PS did you mean "better phrase", or are you actually looking for something with an element of bitterness?

Comment: Yes, bitterness element comes from my guess about reaction of average joe/jane about how his/her tax money are misused. I guess corruption will be the best word to describe that connotation.

Comment: Is the idea in the sawing metaphor to saw off just a little slice for oneself or is it for the corrupt official to take large chunk of the whole? Or some other meaning? This question needs more clarification.

Comment: @Mitch no, it doesn't need more clarification. Is the idea here to exercise fake-dominance through posting comments like yours? That's how you're usually getting your dopamine kick?

Comment: @IlliakaillI You have an interesting question, but because I don't know the context in Russian, it is difficult for me to understand all the nuance that might surround the Russian phrase. You would be helping me help find something appropriate in English if you could add a little more. to your question.

Comment: @Mitch thanks for clarifications, do you believe you can come up with different, more precise idioms based on additional information? Why don't you post several alternative variants that you have in mind, so we can all learn from you ;)

Comment: @IlliakaillI Sure. 'Grant' has a very specific meaning in English, also 'saw', and those two together are very rare in English. But that is really as important as the nuance of the whole phrase Can you give a fill sentence in Russian? (that will really help). What is the feeling you have with 'sawing grants' - is it just cutting off a little bit of a whole big piece, that nobody else would notice? Or is it taking a really large part? Also, is it expected corruption, or is it a shocking  crime out of the ordinary crime? (and do you have any non-metaphorical words in Russian to describe this).

Answer (score 5):

In English, there's the idiom **gravy train**: a way of making money quickly, easily, and often dishonestly.

The Russian idiom "to saw grants" ("пилить гранты") can be roughly reflected by the phrase **to ride (be on) a gravy train**:

> The public should know which senators **are on the corporate gravy train**.

It does not exactly reflect the meaning of the Russian idiom, in which officials "saw off" a bit of state budget (БЮДЖЕТ) to themselves, though.

[image]

Comment: oh thanks! asked another question about gravy train idiom here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569925/what-is-the-origin-of-riding-a-gravy-train-idiom

Comment: Is the idea to cut off a little slice of the log or is it as in the picture to lop off a large piece, maybe even down the middle?